# MPMoviePlayerViewController Video duration

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have no problem playing the video, just cant seem to get my label to update with the video's duration. *(entire video length)*.

### The following method works fine using `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
- (void) updateDurationLabel {

    NSURL *url = /* not an issue */
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *video = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    int duration = video.moviePlayer.playableDuration; /* not the same as AVAudioPlayer */
    int minutesDur = duration / 60;
    int secondsDur = duration % 60;
    NSString *minutesString2 = (minutesDur < 10) ?
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", minutesDur] :
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", minutesDur];
    NSString *secondsString2 = (secondsDur < 10) ?
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", secondsDur] :
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secondsDur];

    lblDuration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", minutesString2,
                                                            secondsString2];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `duration` property may not be accurate until `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification` is sent...

Also you're using `playableDuration` which represents the duration of what have currently been buffered, not the total duration.

Comment: You may be right, I NSLog'd `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification ` but got no response, so that may be the issue.